Wordpress standalone theme - Missing template upon install
I am trying to use Vscode with cpanel, and create a custom theme. I am able to asynchronously connect everything. Howevever, I get this strange error:
Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a templates/index.html or index.php template file. Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet.
My filepath structure is as follows:
wp-content->themes->mytheme->templates->index.html
My filepath for my CSS file is:
wp-content-themes->mytheme->style.css
Inside of my style.css I just have:
Theme Name: mytheme


If your theme is not a block theme, then you need index.php in the root of the theme folder. If it is a block theme, then templates/index.html is needed.
See the WP_Theme::is_block_theme() method for the logic that determines if a theme is a block theme.
In your case, while the file may exist, it may not be readable by WordPress. Check the file's permissions, and adjust if necessary.

I have a templates/index.html inside of my filepath. I even tried cleaning up and changing permissions
